# Porque mi variable no esta guardando el resultado y devuelve 0?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un pequeño programa en javascript pero estoy teniendo un inconveniente cuando realizo una suma me devuelve cero.

Este es el snippet:

```js
alert("Los productos disponibles son: \n \n Bolsos \n Remeras \n Busos \n Paralelas");

let nombreProductoA = "Bolsos";
let stockProductoA = 100;
let precioProductoA = 1000;
let valorCompraA = 0;
let cantidadCompradaA = 0;

let nombreProductoB = "Remeras";
let stockProductoB = 100;
let precioProductoB = 650;
let valorCompraB = 0;
let cantidadCompradaB = 0;

let nombreProductoC = "Busos";
let stockProductoC = 100;
let precioProductoC = 1500;
let valorCompraC = 0;
let cantidadCompradaC = 0;

let nombreProductoD = "Paralelas";
let stockProductoD = 100;
let precioProductoD = 500;
let valorCompraD = 0;
let cantidadCompradaD = 0;

let nuevaCompra = "";

let cantidadEstimada = 0



//----- Funciones Globales -----//

function producto (nombre, precio){
    console.log ("Eligio " + nombre);
    alert("El valor de los " + nombre + " es de $" + precio + " c/u.");
    return nombre, precio;
}

function compra (valor, precio, nombre){
    cantidadEstimada = parseInt(prompt("Que cantidad desea comprar?"));
    valor = precio * cantidadEstimada;
    console.log ("Consumo en " + nombre + " = $" + valor);
    alert ("El valor de su compra de " + nombre + " es de $" + valor);
    return valor;       // CORREGIR valorCompra
}

function stockInsuficiente (stock){
    if (cantidadEstimada > stock){
        alert("No hay suficiente stock")
    }
}

//Repetimos con While hasta que el usuario ingresa "no"

while(nuevaCompra != "no" ){
    console.log("El usuario ingresó " + nuevaCompra);

    let productoEstimado = prompt("Ingrese el producto que desea comprar");

    if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoA){
        producto(nombreProductoA, precioProductoA);
        compra(valorCompraA, precioProductoA, nombreProductoA);
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoA)

    }
    else if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoB){
        producto(nombreProductoB, precioProductoB)
        compra(valorCompraB, precioProductoB, nombreProductoB)
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoB)
    }

    else if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoC){
        producto(nombreProductoC, precioProductoC)
        compra(valorCompraC, precioProductoC, nombreProductoC)
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoC)
    }

    else if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoD){
        producto(nombreProductoD, precioProductoD)
        compra(valorCompraD, precioProductoD, nombreProductoD)
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoD)
    }

    else{
        alert ("No existe el producto ingresado")
    }

    nuevaCompra = prompt("Desea volver a realizar una compra?");
    
}

let gananciaTotal = valorCompraA + valorCompraB + valorCompraC + valorCompraD;

console.log (gananciaTotal)

alert ("El valor total de su compra es de $" + gananciaTotal);
```

El error esta en la siguiente linea de codigo creo yo:

```
let gananciaTotal = valorCompraA + valorCompraB + valorCompraC + valorCompraD;
```

Ya que cuando finalizo la compra es decir ingreso "no" el valor me devuelve cero "0" en vez de la sumatoria de todas las compras. Es como si mi variable no estuviese guardando nada. O tal vez nunca se esta modificando el valor inicial de las variables.

Comment: En tu código, no veo que guardes nada nunca en las variables  `valorCompraA`,  `valorCompraB`, `valorCompraC` o `valorCompraD`. Nunca las utilizas. No entiendo como esperas que tengan algo.

Comment: Veo en tu perfil que has hecho como unas 100 preguntas y tan solo has aceptado una respuesta.  Léete [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar las respuestas que satisfacen tus preguntas. Y este [otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para entender el porque es importante aceptarlas en este sitio. Dejando las preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas **no contribuyes** ni ayudas a la comunidad a mantener este sitio correctamente, pues quedan pendientes para siempre y de tanto en tanto vuelven a ser lanzadas a la comunidad por ello.

Comment: En este sitio se pertende que la colaboración fluya en ambos sentidos, tanto los que preguntan como los que responden, y todos podamos salir beneficiados encontrando las respuestas aceptadas a las preguntas que nos han causado interes. De otro modo parece que trabajamos para ti y **no somos tus empleados**.  Espero que lo entiendas y actues en consecuencia colaborando con el sitio, ya que lo usas muy a menudo dado el alto volumen de preguntas realizadas. Gracias por tu colaboración

Comment: @masterguru no se de que hablas, porque yo aca no veo ninguna respuesta la cual pueda aceptar. Solo comentarios. Saludos.

Comment: @MateoG98 No la hay porque borré mi respuesta al ver tu perfil.  Ahora acabo de volverla a mostrar. De todos modos, me preocupa que de casi 100 preguntas tan solo hayas aceptado una, pues todos los otros que no han tenido el agradecimiento de su esfuerzo y tiempo en contestarte mediante la aceptación de su respuesta no creo que quieran ayudarte más. Te pido por favor que lo tengas en cuenta de ahora en adelante (y si quieres revisar las anteriores mejor) para mejorar este sitio y no dejar las preguntas pendientes para siempre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traducido de [esta página](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/):

> En javascript, todos los argumentos de las funciones son siempre
> pasados por valor. Esto significa que Javascript copia los valores de
> las variables en los argumentos de la función.
>
> Cualquier cambio que se realiza sobre los argumentos dentro de la
> función no queda reflejado en las variables pasadas fuera de la
> función. En otras palabras, los cambios realizados a los argumentos no
> son reflejados fuera de la función.

Por lo tanto, debes modificar estas líneas:

```
function compra (valor, precio, nombre){
compra(valorCompraA, precioProductoA, nombreProductoA);
compra(valorCompraB, precioProductoB, nombreProductoB);
compra(valorCompraC, precioProductoC, nombreProductoC);
compra(valorCompraD, precioProductoD, nombreProductoD);
```

Por estas otras:

```
function compra (precio, nombre){
valorCompraA = compra(precioProductoA, nombreProductoA);
valorCompraB = compra(precioProductoB, nombreProductoB);
valorCompraC = compra(precioProductoC, nombreProductoC);
valorCompraD = compra(precioProductoD, nombreProductoD);
```

Aquí te dejo un snippet funcionando:

```js
alert("Los productos disponibles son: \n \n Bolsos \n Remeras \n Busos \n Paralelas");

let nombreProductoA = "Bolsos";
let stockProductoA = 100;
let precioProductoA = 1000;
let valorCompraA = 0;
let cantidadCompradaA = 0;

let nombreProductoB = "Remeras";
let stockProductoB = 100;
let precioProductoB = 650;
let valorCompraB = 0;
let cantidadCompradaB = 0;

let nombreProductoC = "Busos";
let stockProductoC = 100;
let precioProductoC = 1500;
let valorCompraC = 0;
let cantidadCompradaC = 0;

let nombreProductoD = "Paralelas";
let stockProductoD = 100;
let precioProductoD = 500;
let valorCompraD = 0;
let cantidadCompradaD = 0;

let nuevaCompra = "";

let cantidadEstimada = 0



//----- Funciones Globales -----//

function producto (nombre, precio){
    console.log ("Eligio " + nombre);
    alert("El valor de los " + nombre + " es de $" + precio + " c/u.");
    return nombre, precio;
}

function compra (precio, nombre){
    cantidadEstimada = parseInt(prompt("Que cantidad desea comprar?"));
    valor = precio * cantidadEstimada;
    console.log ("Consumo en " + nombre + " = $" + valor);
    alert ("El valor de su compra de " + nombre + " es de $" + valor);
    return valor;       // CORREGIR valorCompra
}

function stockInsuficiente (stock){
    if (cantidadEstimada > stock){
        alert("No hay suficiente stock")
    }
}

//Repetimos con While hasta que el usuario ingresa "no"

while(nuevaCompra != "no" ){
    console.log("El usuario ingresó " + nuevaCompra);

    let productoEstimado = prompt("Ingrese el producto que desea comprar");

    if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoA){
        producto(nombreProductoA, precioProductoA);
        valorCompraA = compra(precioProductoA, nombreProductoA);
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoA)

    }
    else if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoB){
        producto(nombreProductoB, precioProductoB)
        valorCompraB = compra(precioProductoB, nombreProductoB);
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoB)
    }

    else if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoC){
        producto(nombreProductoC, precioProductoC)
        valorCompraC = compra(precioProductoC, nombreProductoC);
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoC)
    }

    else if (productoEstimado == nombreProductoD){
        producto(nombreProductoD, precioProductoD)
        valorCompraD = compra(precioProductoD, nombreProductoD);
        stockInsuficiente (stockProductoD)
    }

    else{
        alert ("No existe el producto ingresado")
    }

    nuevaCompra = prompt("Desea volver a realizar una compra?");
    
}

let gananciaTotal = valorCompraA + valorCompraB + valorCompraC + valorCompraD;

console.log (gananciaTotal)

alert ("El valor total de su compra es de $" + gananciaTotal);
```

Comment: De hecho, no todos son pasados por valor. Los objetos y los arreglos pasan por referencia.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Léete ese mismo enlace que he puesto en la respuesta, un poco más abajo, y verás lo que dicen al respecto.

Comment: Si, entiendo que muchas personas consideran que el "valor" de un objeto es su referencia, por lo que puede ser válido. Pero se presta bastante a confusión. Esa misma línea de "Cualquier cambio que se realiza sobre los argumentos dentro de la función no queda reflejado en las variables pasadas fuera de la función. " es la que me hace un poco de ruido, ya que cuando pasas un objeto como parámetro y modificas el objeto dentro de la función se modifica el objeto original.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez veo que no te has leido el ejemplo de ese enlace hasta el final... fíjate bien en la última asignación, la cual segun tu teoria deberia modificar el objeto original, pero no lo hace... cuando dice eso de `obj = { name: 'Jane', age: 22 };` y luego no se aplica en el objeto pasado `person`.  Es una vieja discusión, no hace falta extenderla demasiado más aquí.

Comment: De cualquier forma es buena tu respuesta. Hay toda una discusión sobre si es por referencia o por valor [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language#:~:text=It's%20always%20pass%20by%20value,look%20like%20pass%20by%20reference.). Solo considero me suena feo eso de "copia los valores" para casos no primitivos. Supongo java y c# me han hecho mucho daño XD.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Como no tengo ni idea ni de java ni de c# no tengo esos dilemas :-)  Aplico tabla rasa y me lo creo todo y miro de abstraerlo para hacerlo comprensible para mi.  En cuanto a mi respuesta, tan solo soluciono la "parte" de la pregunta en su código, pero puede fallar en distintos puntos por otros motivos, pero eso ya es cosa del OP averiguarlo y solucionarlo.